# PHP form with multiple attachments "foreach"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, phpmailer, email-attachments

```
$mail_to_send = new PHPMailer();

$mail_to_send->FromName = $author;
$mail_to_send->From     = $email;
$mail_to_send->Subject  = $subject;
$mail_to_send->Body     = "Mittente: ". $author . "\n" . "\n" . "Contatto di 
riferimento: " . $contatto . "\n" . "\n" . "Tipo di annuncio: " . $tipo . 
"\n" . "\n". $message;

$mail_to_send->AddReplyTo($email);
//contact form destination e-mail:
$mail_to_send->AddAddress('mymail@gmail.com'); 
foreach ($_FILES['attachment'] as $_allegato){

if ( !$_allegato['attachment']['error'] == 4 ) { //something was send


    if ( $_allegato['attachment']['error'] == 0 && 
    is_uploaded_file($_allegato['attachment']['tmp_name']) )


        $mail_to_send->AddAttachment($_allegato['attachment']['tmp_name'], 
        $_allegato['attachment']['name']);

    else 

    wp_die('Error: there was a problem with the file upload. Try again 
    later.');
    }   
   }
```

Why is my foreach not working? `foreach ($_FILES['attachment'] as $_allegato){`

I need to send multiple attachments with $mail_to_send but i'm not familiar with php $files.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there some data? Try var_dump($_FILES['attachment']); and add output here.

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['attachment']) inside the "foreach"?

Comment: What **exactly** makes you think that the loop is not working?

Comment: php $files manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: @NicoHaase in the e-mail i receive there are no attachments

Comment: And have you tried debugging your code? Is the attachment added properly (such that `AddAttachment` is called)?

Comment: @NicoHaase With just one attachment everything works fine... The problem started when i added the possibility to upload more attachments. And i'm almost sure that i'm doing something wrong with that foreach.

Comment: Maybe. But you should really start debugging your code, either through `var_dump` or `echo` or whatever

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok, i'll try. Thx for your answers.

Comment: You could always [take a look at the multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps).